# Apache runs locally but can't be accessed from other machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, apache-http-server, iptables

I'm running Apache 2.2.3 in a VM for a test environment on CentOS 5. Apache is running and responding to requests on the VM itself. If I run "lynx localhost" on the VM I do get my test page.

When I try to access Apache from my actual PC I get nothing. SSH works to the VM but nothing with Apache. I set up iptables on the VM to be open to anything but HTTP requests from my PC still return nothing (I get timeouts when I telnet over port 80 to the VM and my browser just says "cannot open page on 172.16.x.y").

What else should I check?

Comment: What is your Network Setting in Virtualbox? Is it Bridged?

Comment: @Petkaux Yes, it is bridged. Should I change this?

Answer (score 3):

Check where Apache is listening:

```
$ sudo netstat -nlp | grep apache
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    4720/apache2    
                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

If you see `127.0.0.1` as above, your Apache is only listening on the loopback interface, and other machines won't be able to connect to it.  Look for a `Listen` directive in your Apache config, which will look something like

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

If you remove the `127.0.0.1` (so you just have `Listen 80`) and restart Apache, it should then be listening on all available addresses.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried that. In netstat it shows it's listening on 0.0.0.0:80

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Flup, but there are other things you might want to try as well -

Can you use Lynx to go to the URL by its iP address from the VM, ie `lynx http://1.2.3.4` should look more closely at the VM configuration / network.

Comment: I tried to lynx on its IP address (not localhost) and it did successfully display the test page. I suspect you're right because SSH to this host DOES work.

Comment: That means you have a networking problem between your VM and the world.  Try debugging that.  Unfortunately you have not provided details sufficient to point you in the correct direction, but it may well have to do with the VM host / Dom0 doing NAT rather then bridging.  This is most likely the case if you can ping out from inside the VM

Comment: the problem isn't networking if SSH and ping works but Apache doesn't. I did provide a good amount of details; maybe you could offer more helpful advice before editorializing.

Comment: I'm only a Linux system administrator (for ISP's and web providers) of 20 years. You didn't specify the VM architecture, let alone mtr results, route tables or firewall rules. I wish you luck solving your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sounded sarcastic. It was a long day! I did actually state that I opened IP tables to allow anything, but I digress. To be honest, I don't always know what details are relevant - sometimes I put in too much detail and I get chided, other times I don't put in enough. Thanks for your help.